# android exception while populating a list view

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

While attempting to populate the items in a ListView following the outcome of a switch statement, I am encountering some sort of error. The application force closes inside the emulator, and when I ran it through the Eclipse debugger it shows the main thread has hung due to an IllegalStateException.

Aside from it meaning the obvious that it has entered some sort of wrong state, how do I fix it? I'm trying to do all of this from inside an OnItemClickListener, so that when the item is clicked, a switch statement evaluates which item was clicked, and then assigns an according ListAdapter to the ListView depending on the outcome of the switch. Is this the correct way to go about it? And if so, what in my code below is throwing the error?

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
    final String[] autos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.auto_array);
    final ListAdapter la_auto = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, autos);
```

And then further down in the portion dealing with the onclicklistener

```
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            switch(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition())
            {
            case 0:
                lv.setAdapter(la_auto);
                break;
```

EDIT: The LogCat stack trace is stopping at this error, "You must supply a Resource ID for a TextView, and the stack is hung at this point: ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(int, View, ViewGroup, int) line: 347

Any suggestions? I imagine it has something to do with the parameters I'm passing to the onItemClicked method.

Comment: You should paste the stacktrace using logcat.

Comment: Yup, that logcat trace made all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

The answer is in [simple_list_item_2.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml;h=5eab54eb7e0603ae0d88c067bdb84b0e643db8f0;hb=refs/heads/master):

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
```

You need to use a resource that contains only a `TextView`. [simple_list_item_1.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml;h=c9c77a5f9c113a9d331d5e11a6016aaa815ec771;hb=refs/heads/master) fits the bill:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
```

Try browsing other possibilities [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/layout;h=3c81d0a9f3cf1b966ef7e8a8c590bc6a604a944f;hb=refs/heads/master) or making your own if you don't see any you like.

Comment: Working like a charm now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to start a new `Activity` with a new `ListView` and adapter.

You can pass the selected item as a parameter in your `Intent`:

```
Intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
intent.putExtra("selected", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

and retrieve it later in your other activity's `onCreate` method with:

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("selected");
```

You may want to think about what information you would like to share between the activities. Using multiple activities will allow your user to press the back button and return to the original list as well.

Comment: Not sure that would work for what I'm trying to do here as I'm trying to fill the view dynamically as the users scrolls through a Gallery.

Comment: Ah, yes, then you wouldn't be able to use multiple activities